# Errors with installing Freenx on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

I am trying to install remote desktop on an ubuntu ec2 instance by using NX, i have done `sudo -E apt-get update` & `sudo -E apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop`. then to install freenx `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team` but from here forward when I do `sudo apt-get update` it gives me some errors:

> Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages   404  Not
>   Found
>
> Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US
>
> Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/freenx-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead

Then when I type `sudo aptitude install -y freenx` it gives me another error which is:

> "Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "freenx"

I have googled it and found different suggestions but none of them works, it became a real headache for me, appreciate your help.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this, I have the exact same problem!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to remove your old ppa first with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:freenx-team
```

Then I think you need to try the command below for trusty and new versions of ubuntu.  Note the `/trusty` on the end.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:freenx-team/trusty
```

On my machine I  had to use `aptitude` rather than `apt-get` for some reason unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

freenx is not available for trusty yet, the latest supported ubuntu distro is precise. So if you want to install it then you probably need to download it from the ubuntu precise repository.

Go [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/freenx-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/) to see the list of ubuntu distros supported by freenx

There is another way too, but I can't guarantee that either of these process will work, because of dependency issues.

The second way you can try installing this is to edit the ppa file that was created for that ppa. It's located in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
look for a file named closely that of your software name and open it with root privilege and replace any trusty with precise and save the file then run `sudo apt-get update`
and then `sudo apt-get install freenx`